# How can I solve this differential equation $x(x+1)y' + y = \arctan(x)$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I've been trying to solve this differential equation:

$x(x+1)y' + y = \arctan(x)$

and that is a linear differential equation after a small reform: $y' + \frac{1}{x(x+1)} y = \frac{\arctan(x)}{x(x+1)}$.

What I did was try using an integrating factor $u(x) = \exp(\int{\frac{1}{x(x+1)}})$
and I found $u(x)=\exp(
−
\ln
(
∣
\frac{1}{x}
+
C|)$

the general solution of the differential equation is expressed as :

$y = \frac{{\int {u\left( x \right)f\left( x \right)dx} + C}}{{u\left( x \right)}}$
, where $f(x)=\frac{\arctan(x)}{x(x+1)}$ and $C$ is an arbitrary constant.
But I don't think I can do any more than this, is there a way I can get to find it ?

Comment: The integrating factor simplifies to $\frac{x}{1+x}$ (and you have a mistake or typo: it's $-\log|1/x+1|+C$ and note the integration constant is irrelevant so you can just set $C=0$).

Answer (score 2):

$$y' + \frac{1}{x(x+1)} y = \frac{\arctan(x)}{x(x+1)}$$
Your integrating factor should be:
$$\mu (x)=\exp \int \dfrac {dx}{x(x+1)}=\dfrac x {x+1}$$
The constant is not needed.
$$\left(\dfrac  {yx}{x+1}\right)'=\dfrac {\arctan x}{(x+1)^2}$$
Integrate by part:
$$\left(\dfrac  {yx}{x+1}\right)=-\dfrac {\arctan x}{x+1}+\int\dfrac {dx}{(x+1)(x^2+1)}$$
Decompose the fraction:
$$\left(\dfrac  {yx}{x+1}\right)=-\dfrac {\arctan x}{x+1}+ \dfrac12  \int \dfrac {dx}{x+1}-\dfrac 12\int\dfrac {x-1}{x^2+1}dx$$

$$......................$$

Comment: Oups thank you @LutzLehmann It's corrected.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your integration factor is wrong, it should be $\frac{x}{x+1}$ then you multiply everything by the integration factor. And check the derivative of $\frac{x}{x+1}$ is $\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}$.